# xCode: Release version of app has bug that identical developer build does not

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, release

I released an app today which I thought I had tested vigorously. A friend brought to my attention that the tab bar controller, a crucial part of the app, simply did not work, as though user interaction were disabled. Tapping other tabs did not reveal the view controller for that tab. The tab bar item icons didn't even change, like they're supposed to when selected. They were simply stuck on the first view controller.

The weirdest part is when I took both my friend's iPhone and mine (hers a 5S, mine a 5C) and then redownloaded the app on both devices. The bug persisted on hers, but the tab bar worked completely normally on mine. Other people have complained about the same bug, but I cannot replicate it on my own phone. I could not even replicate it in several versions of Xcode Simulator. I had never seen it before.

I have already submitted a new build in which I had to force the tab bar controller to display the appropriate tab under the `didSelect` method, but my app will essentially be broken until the Review Board accepts it.

What could have caused this?

EDIT: The newly uploaded build still isn't working properly. Even innocuous changes aren't taking effect. I've downloaded the new version on both phones - mine shows the new navigation bar button in the top right, but the other phone still has the old button. And they are both running the same version.

[image: One device shows the new navbar button.][image: Other device shows the old navbar button. These are both running the same version from the app store.]

Answer (score 3):

It's likely the bug is related to code that is compiled differently between debug and release modes due to different optimizer settings.

There are two main categories:

1. **Use of uninitialized variables**: The value of the uninitialized variable is technically undefined, but in the debug builds it can be pretty "stable" (e.g. always equaling zero due to the variable's location in memory and what was in that location before).  When you compile in Release and the location of the variable changes, or the order of initialization changes, your variable now has a different value and the code behavior changes.
   Luckily for this class of bugs Xcode can help.  Select "*Analyze*" from the "*Product*" menu and pay close attention to all the errors marked in blue.
2. **Timing bugs**: Typically code in Release runs faster so if you are doing anything async/multi-threaded, you may trigger timing related bugs in Release that weren't evident in Debug.  I'm not sure if this is relevant for your case, though I can imagine some scenarios where a timing bug could cause views to get messed up internal state.  It's hard to say without seeing your code.

Please note that changing architectures (5S is 64 bit and 5C is 32 bit) is also a factor in both of the above categories.

Comment: The release version is working for either or both of these reasons: I change the optimization level to None, and I addressed every Analyze issue. Thanks.